# The Activity class declared in your AndroidManifest.xml is wrong or has not provided the correct FlutterEngine

Tags: android, flutter, dart, audio

i need to do audio work in background

this the code

### audio_handler file

```
import 'package:audio_service/audio_service.dart';
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';

Future<AudioHandler> initAudioService() async {
  return await AudioService.init(
    builder: () => MyAudioHandler(),
    config: const AudioServiceConfig(
      androidNotificationChannelId: 'com.mycompany.myapp.audio',
      androidNotificationChannelName: 'Audio Service Demo',
      androidNotificationOngoing: true,
      androidStopForegroundOnPause: true,
    ),
  );
}

class MyAudioHandler extends BaseAudioHandler {
  final _player = AudioPlayer();
  final _playlist = ConcatenatingAudioSource(children: []);

  MyAudioHandler() {
    _loadEmptyPlaylist();
    _notifyAudioHandlerAboutPlaybackEvents();
    _listenForDurationChanges();
    _listenForCurrentSongIndexChanges();
    _listenForSequenceStateChanges();
  }

  Future<void> _loadEmptyPlaylist() async {
    try {
      await _player.setAudioSource(_playlist);
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error: $e");
    }
  }

  void _notifyAudioHandlerAboutPlaybackEvents() {
    _player.playbackEventStream.listen((PlaybackEvent event) {
      final playing = _player.playing;
      playbackState.add(playbackState.value.copyWith(
        controls: [
          MediaControl.skipToPrevious,
          if (playing) MediaControl.pause else MediaControl.play,
          MediaControl.stop,
          MediaControl.skipToNext,
        ],
        systemActions: const {
          MediaAction.seek,
        },
        androidCompactActionIndices: const [0, 1, 3],
        processingState: const {
          ProcessingState.idle: AudioProcessingState.idle,
          ProcessingState.loading: AudioProcessingState.loading,
          ProcessingState.buffering: AudioProcessingState.buffering,
          ProcessingState.ready: AudioProcessingState.ready,
          ProcessingState.completed: AudioProcessingState.completed,
        }[_player.processingState]!,
        repeatMode: const {
          LoopMode.off: AudioServiceRepeatMode.none,
          LoopMode.one: AudioServiceRepeatMode.one,
          LoopMode.all: AudioServiceRepeatMode.all,
        }[_player.loopMode]!,
        shuffleMode: (_player.shuffleModeEnabled)
            ? AudioServiceShuffleMode.all
            : AudioServiceShuffleMode.none,
        playing: playing,
        updatePosition: _player.position,
        bufferedPosition: _player.bufferedPosition,
        speed: _player.speed,
        queueIndex: event.currentIndex,
      ));
    });
  }

  void _listenForDurationChanges() {
    _player.durationStream.listen((duration) {
      var index = _player.currentIndex;
      final newQueue = queue.value;
      if (index == null || newQueue.isEmpty) return;
      if (_player.shuffleModeEnabled) {
        index = _player.shuffleIndices!.indexOf(index);
      }
      final oldMediaItem = newQueue[index];
      final newMediaItem = oldMediaItem.copyWith(duration: duration);
      newQueue[index] = newMediaItem;
      queue.add(newQueue);
      mediaItem.add(newMediaItem);
    });
  }

  void _listenForCurrentSongIndexChanges() {
    _player.currentIndexStream.listen((index) {
      final playlist = queue.value;
      if (index == null || playlist.isEmpty) return;
      if (_player.shuffleModeEnabled) {
        index = _player.shuffleIndices!.indexOf(index);
      }
      mediaItem.add(playlist[index]);
    });
  }

  void _listenForSequenceStateChanges() {
    _player.sequenceStateStream.listen((SequenceState? sequenceState) {
      final sequence = sequenceState?.effectiveSequence;
      if (sequence == null || sequence.isEmpty) return;
      final items = sequence.map((source) => source.tag as MediaItem);
      queue.add(items.toList());
    });
  }

  @override
  Future<void> addQueueItems(List<MediaItem> mediaItems) async {
    // manage Just Audio
    final audioSource = mediaItems.map(_createAudioSource);
    _playlist.addAll(audioSource.toList());

    // notify system
    final newQueue = queue.value..addAll(mediaItems);
    queue.add(newQueue);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> addQueueItem(MediaItem mediaItem) async {
    // manage Just Audio
    final audioSource = _createAudioSource(mediaItem);
    _playlist.add(audioSource);

    // notify system
    final newQueue = queue.value..add(mediaItem);
    queue.add(newQueue);
  }

  UriAudioSource _createAudioSource(MediaItem mediaItem) {
    return AudioSource.uri(
      Uri.parse(mediaItem.extras!['url'] as String),
      tag: mediaItem,
    );
  }

  @override
  Future<void> removeQueueItemAt(int index) async {
    // manage Just Audio
    _playlist.removeAt(index);

    // notify system
    final newQueue = queue.value..removeAt(index);
    queue.add(newQueue);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> play() => _player.play();

  @override
  Future<void> pause() => _player.pause();

  @override
  Future<void> seek(Duration position) => _player.seek(position);

  @override
  Future<void> skipToQueueItem(int index) async {
    if (index < 0 || index >= queue.value.length) return;
    if (_player.shuffleModeEnabled) {
      index = _player.shuffleIndices![index];
    }
    _player.seek(Duration.zero, index: index);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> skipToNext() => _player.seekToNext();

  @override
  Future<void> skipToPrevious() => _player.seekToPrevious();

  @override
  Future<void> setRepeatMode(AudioServiceRepeatMode repeatMode) async {
    switch (repeatMode) {
      case AudioServiceRepeatMode.none:
        _player.setLoopMode(LoopMode.off);
        break;
      case AudioServiceRepeatMode.one:
        _player.setLoopMode(LoopMode.one);
        break;
      case AudioServiceRepeatMode.group:
      case AudioServiceRepeatMode.all:
        _player.setLoopMode(LoopMode.all);
        break;
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<void> setShuffleMode(AudioServiceShuffleMode shuffleMode) async {
    if (shuffleMode == AudioServiceShuffleMode.none) {
      _player.setShuffleModeEnabled(false);
    } else {
      await _player.shuffle();
      _player.setShuffleModeEnabled(true);
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<void> customAction(String name, [Map<String, dynamic>? extras]) async {
    if (name == 'dispose') {
      await _player.dispose();
      super.stop();
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<void> stop() async {
    await _player.stop();
    return super.stop();
  }
}
```

### Service_Locator file

```
import 'package:audio_service/audio_service.dart';
import '../page_manager.dart';
import 'audio_handler.dart';
import 'playlist_repository.dart';
import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';

GetIt getIt = GetIt.instance;

Future<void> setupServiceLocator() async {
  // services
  getIt.registerSingleton<AudioHandler>(await initAudioService());
  getIt.registerLazySingleton<PlaylistRepository>(() => DemoPlaylist());

  // page state
  getIt.registerLazySingleton<PageManager>(() => PageManager());
}
```

### call audio file

```
class Audio_Calling extends StatefulWidget {
  const Audio_Calling({super.key});

  @override
  State<Audio_Calling> createState() => _Audio_CallingState();
}

class _Audio_CallingState extends State<Audio_Calling> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    
    getIt<PageManager>().init();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    getIt<PageManager>().dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Column(
            children: const [
              CurrentSongTitle(),
              Playlist(),
              AddRemoveSongButtons(),
              AudioProgressBar(),
              AudioControlButtons(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### page maneger file

```
class PageManager {
  // Listeners: Updates going to the UI
  final currentSongTitleNotifier = ValueNotifier<String>('');
  final playlistNotifier = ValueNotifier<List<String>>([]);
  final progressNotifier = ProgressNotifier();
  final repeatButtonNotifier = RepeatButtonNotifier();
  final isFirstSongNotifier = ValueNotifier<bool>(true);
  final playButtonNotifier = PlayButtonNotifier();
  final isLastSongNotifier = ValueNotifier<bool>(true);
  final isShuffleModeEnabledNotifier = ValueNotifier<bool>(false);

  final _audioHandler = getIt<AudioHandler>();

  // Events: Calls coming from the UI
  void init() async {
    await _loadPlaylist();
    _listenToChangesInPlaylist();
    _listenToPlaybackState();
    _listenToCurrentPosition();
    _listenToBufferedPosition();
    _listenToTotalDuration();
    _listenToChangesInSong();
  }

  Future<void> _loadPlaylist() async {
    final songRepository = getIt<PlaylistRepository>();
    final playlist = await songRepository.fetchInitialPlaylist();
    final mediaItems = playlist
        .map((song) => MediaItem(
              id: song['id'] ?? '',
              album: song['album'] ?? '',
              title: song['title'] ?? '',
              extras: {'url': song['url']},
            ))
        .toList();
    _audioHandler.addQueueItems(mediaItems);
  }

  void _listenToChangesInPlaylist() {
    _audioHandler.queue.listen((playlist) {
      if (playlist.isEmpty) {
        playlistNotifier.value = [];
        currentSongTitleNotifier.value = '';
      } else {
        final newList = playlist.map((item) => item.title).toList();
        playlistNotifier.value = newList;
      }
      _updateSkipButtons();
    });
  }

  void _listenToPlaybackState() {
    _audioHandler.playbackState.listen((playbackState) {
      final isPlaying = playbackState.playing;
      final processingState = playbackState.processingState;
      if (processingState == AudioProcessingState.loading ||
          processingState == AudioProcessingState.buffering) {
        playButtonNotifier.value = ButtonState.loading;
      } else if (!isPlaying) {
        playButtonNotifier.value = ButtonState.paused;
      } else if (processingState != AudioProcessingState.completed) {
        playButtonNotifier.value = ButtonState.playing;
      } else {
        _audioHandler.seek(Duration.zero);
        _audioHandler.pause();
      }
    });
  }

  void _listenToCurrentPosition() {
    AudioService.position.listen((position) {
      final oldState = progressNotifier.value;
      progressNotifier.value = ProgressBarState(
        current: position,
        buffered: oldState.buffered,
        total: oldState.total,
      );
    });
  }

  void _listenToBufferedPosition() {
    _audioHandler.playbackState.listen((playbackState) {
      final oldState = progressNotifier.value;
      progressNotifier.value = ProgressBarState(
        current: oldState.current,
        buffered: playbackState.bufferedPosition,
        total: oldState.total,
      );
    });
  }

  void _listenToTotalDuration() {
    _audioHandler.mediaItem.listen((mediaItem) {
      final oldState = progressNotifier.value;
      progressNotifier.value = ProgressBarState(
        current: oldState.current,
        buffered: oldState.buffered,
        total: mediaItem?.duration ?? Duration.zero,
      );
    });
  }

  void _listenToChangesInSong() {
    _audioHandler.mediaItem.listen((mediaItem) {
      currentSongTitleNotifier.value = mediaItem?.title ?? '';
      _updateSkipButtons();
    });
  }

  void _updateSkipButtons() {
    final mediaItem = _audioHandler.mediaItem.value;
    final playlist = _audioHandler.queue.value;
    if (playlist.length < 2 || mediaItem == null) {
      isFirstSongNotifier.value = true;
      isLastSongNotifier.value = true;
    } else {
      isFirstSongNotifier.value = playlist.first == mediaItem;
      isLastSongNotifier.value = playlist.last == mediaItem;
    }
  }

  void play() => _audioHandler.play();
  void pause() => _audioHandler.pause();

  void seek(Duration position) => _audioHandler.seek(position);

  void previous() => _audioHandler.skipToPrevious();
  void next() => _audioHandler.skipToNext();

  void repeat() {
    repeatButtonNotifier.nextState();
    final repeatMode = repeatButtonNotifier.value;
    switch (repeatMode) {
      case RepeatState.off:
        _audioHandler.setRepeatMode(AudioServiceRepeatMode.none);
        break;
      case RepeatState.repeatSong:
        _audioHandler.setRepeatMode(AudioServiceRepeatMode.one);
        break;
      case RepeatState.repeatPlaylist:
        _audioHandler.setRepeatMode(AudioServiceRepeatMode.all);
        break;
    }
  }

  void shuffle() {
    final enable = !isShuffleModeEnabledNotifier.value;
    isShuffleModeEnabledNotifier.value = enable;
    if (enable) {
      _audioHandler.setShuffleMode(AudioServiceShuffleMode.all);
    } else {
      _audioHandler.setShuffleMode(AudioServiceShuffleMode.none);
    }
  }

  Future<void> add() async {
    final songRepository = getIt<PlaylistRepository>();
    final song = await songRepository.fetchAnotherSong();
    final mediaItem = MediaItem(
      id: song['id'] ?? '',
      album: song['album'] ?? '',
      title: song['title'] ?? '',
      extras: {'url': song['url']},
    );
    _audioHandler.addQueueItem(mediaItem);
  }

  void remove() {
    final lastIndex = _audioHandler.queue.value.length - 1;
    if (lastIndex < 0) return;
    _audioHandler.removeQueueItemAt(lastIndex);
  }

  void dispose() {
    _audioHandler.customAction('dispose');
  }

  void stop() {
    _audioHandler.stop();
  }
}
```

### main

```
void main() async {
  BlocOverrides.runZoned(
    () async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      await setupServiceLocator();
      
runApp(Audio_Calling());
})}
```

when i run my code i get this error:
PlatformException (PlatformException(The Activity class declared in your AndroidManifest.xml is wrong or has not provided the correct FlutterEngine. Please see the README for instructions., null, null, null))
[image]
how can i solve it

Comment: I get a similar error; ever solve it?

Answer (score 0):

you should change your Activity Name to audio service activity

[image]